# wifi connection speed in AC

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I have Intel wifi 8265 card installed. I also install drives for that card. However I can't obtain speed more than 54M (54M is limit for N) I know the card can do AC (up to 867M).
Why did Ubuntu deny to connection as AC mode? I have few networks N, AC.
I even can't connect to AC network.
How for fix that?

Comment: I have no trouble connecting at AC speeds to my seperate 5 GHz network set to 802.11a/n/ac mixed mode. Is that what you have? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have 3 wifi networks: 2.5Gh (N mode only) can connect with Link 54Mb, 5Gh (N/AC mixed) cannot connect at all, 5 Gh can connect with speed link 54Mb(auto). Speed 54Mb means standard N. Point is to have speed AC or >54Mb

Comment: Are they named differently or all the same?

Comment: Can you see the 5 GHz (N/AC mixed) with: `sudo iwlist scan` Is it on a channel that the Intel wireless does? `sudo iwlist chan`

Comment: Cell 15 - Address: 1C:B7:2C:DC:28:14
     Channel:36
               Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
       Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
       Encryption key:on
     ESSID:"goodidea-spider_5G"
        Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
         36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
     Mode:Master
       Extra:tsf=000000027de339ae
     Extra: Last beacon: 1972ms ago
                  IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
           Group Cipher : CCMP
    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
      Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

Comment: wlp112s0  32 channels in total; available frequencies :
Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
 Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
 Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz

Comment: remaining:   Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
Current Frequency:5.745 GHz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84127/discussion-between-chili555-and-konstantin-pupkov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our chat, we discovered that, based on a suggestion from a vendor of Linux computers, you added a line to /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf that said:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Your router is set to mixed mode 802.11N/AC.

Typically, routers will negotiate with client devices and connect at the lowest speed and, if both the host and the client advertise that they are capable, shift to higher and then higher speeds. I suspect that, as soon as your wireless card reported that it was incapable of 802.11N, the router refused to connect.

You removed the line from the iwlwifi.conf file and rebooted. You connected to the 5 GHz segment of the router immediately.

We looked at the channel occupancy in your area with:

```
nmcli dev wifi list
```

We saw no other SSID on channel 149 and confirmed that your Intel has channel 149 as an available channel.

```
sudo iwlist chan
```

You changed the router to channel 149 and connected. iwconfig confirmed: `Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s`.

I think you are all set.